# How to put RecyclerView below Toolbar and above TabLayout and ViewPager also handling responses to scrolls in a custom manner?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to create a layout like the below image:

[image]

A CoordinatorLayout which contain  :

1. CollapsingToolbarLayout( contain ImageView & Toolbar)
2. RecyclerView
3. TabLayout
4. ViewPager( that each fragment of it contain a RecyclerView)

I wanna responding to scroll events in this way:

1. CollapsingToolbarLayout expand and collapse by scrolling
2. Toolbar sticks to the top until TabLayout reach to the top
3. After that toolbar scroll up and TabLayout stick to the top

I'm having trouble with the RecyclerView between CollapsingToolbarLayout and TabLayout. I can implement this layout without that RecyclerView( I put CollapsingToolbarLayout and TabLayout inside the AppBarLayout and the ViewPager outside it, inside the CoordinatorLayout).

**My Question:**

1. Where should I put that RecyclerView?
2. Which & where `layout_scrollFlags` and `layout_behavior` should I set for each layouts?

It seems that AppBarLayout have a limited height. When I put the RecyclerView inside AppBarLayout, only a portion part of the RecyclerView is visible and also TabLayout disappear.

I read lots of tutorials like [this one](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#responding-to-scroll-events) and lots of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766172/recyclerview-and-viewpager-with-collapsing-toolbar) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958749/collapsing-toolbar-layout-with-viewpager-inside-nestedscrollview), but non of them help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? And to be honest, if you are gonna have both recycler view and the view pager/ tab layout, the prob is that ur recycler view will be dynamic cause the item content will change and so you might end up getting those scroll problems.

Comment: I have tries these 2 scroll view will drive you insane
best solution limit the first layout to 3 with a show more button that creates a popup or add them in a liner if the number is not large and then add the tab and the scroll view

Answer (score 4):

use this as a main layout

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/co_profile_activity_root_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:visibility="visible">
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_img_placeholder_height"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar_profile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rel_top"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_bg_placeholder_profile"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:tint="#11000000"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/lin_top_inner"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="#BF473e6b"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop">
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/frame_detail_profile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3">
                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_profile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_toolbar_height"
                        android:gravity="top|center"
                        app:layout_anchor="@id/frame_detail_profile"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                        app:title="">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_title"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_toolbar_title_left_margin"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab_layout_profile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_tab_layout_top_margin"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:tabTextColor="@color/charcoal_grey" />
                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and for grid layout of tabs use adapter classes.

Comment: Nice solution !

Answer (score 0):

Start with `AppBarLayout` under which you add `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with *scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"*,

add `LinearLayout` with *vertical orientation* to `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and add the

- `FrameLayout` with `ImageView` + `Toolbar`
- `RecyclerView`
- `TabLayout`

Comment: I don't think it works, share your code on github please!

Answer (score 0):

**Two things to be done:-**

1. When the search button is clicked, set the visibility of recycler view to VISIBLE
2. When the back button is pressed, set the visibility of recycler view to GONE

Following are the implementations:

**1. Setting the visibility of recycler view to VISIBLE:**

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.searchView) {
            rView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**2. Setting the visibility of recycle adapter to GONE**

```
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchView);
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchMenuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(GONE);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**NOTE:** Do not forget to keep the visibilty as GONE initially when the activity is started

Answer (score 0):

I know I might be late to this answer but I have also been trying to implement this for a while. The solution I have feels a bit hacky but it is an option for trying to get the tabs to stick. In a simpler solution lets say we wanted the following:

1. A Collapsing toolbar layout
2. Which links to a scroll view.
   In that scroll view we want the following:
3. A recyclerview that say scrolls horizontally
4. Below the recycler view a tab layout
5. Below the tab layout we want a view pager that will load dynamic fragments within a fixed space.

**`activity_scrolling.xml`** the outer parent xml file may look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".temp.ScrollingActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then the inner **`content_scrolling.xml`** may look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".temp.ScrollingActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A Heading"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_xl"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="680dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This will allow you to forcefully place the tab layout in a location of your choosing (even if its after a recyler view).

The hacky part which i dont like is this specific line `android:layout_height="680dp"` which forces the viewpager height to be something specific. I am not sure why `wrap_content` or `match_parent` do not work. But this is the best thing to a solution I can provide for the issue of placing TabLayout and ViewPager in specific places.