# Android fixed navigation header with scroll

Tags: android

In Android i wanted to achieve something. I don't have design with me so please assume the following,

1. In a screen top layer is image and below that some header/menu items.
   When scroll to that second layer position the menu has to move on top (fixed navigation header) and all the below items should scroll without affecting the menu.

If I scroll back to first layer position . Then only the menu has to come down .

Below that header view the menu items should move to top(should not move)
[image]

something like this, i need in android.. https://m3.material.io/components/menus/guidelines

[image]

On scroll down
[image]
Could some one suggest any reference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40283773/12833551
May be this answer will help you